# Changing the custom domain when using GitHub Pages with a redirect to the new domain

Tags: http-status-code-301, github-pages

I have a site hosted on GitHub Pages at `1.example.com`. I want to move it to `2.example.com`, and have `1.example.com` redirect (HTTP 301) the visitor to `2.example.com`. Is there any way to do this using DNS records alone?

The domain's administrator tried creating a `CNAME` record for `1.example.com` to point to `2.example.com`, but now `1.example.com` shows a 404 page because GitHub Pages will only serve content at `2.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a HTTP 301 redirect with DNS. You'll need to run an HTTP server to do the redirect. Some DNS providers include this service (Google Domains, DynDns, etc.).